# C# How to connect to Oracle database and necessary connectio nattributes

Tags: c#, database, oracle, database-connection

I have an Oracle database that I am trying to connect to. I am new to connecting to databases in C#. I have been researching online, but I get all kinds of different answers / responses that leave me even more confused.

I am trying to understand what is needed to connect to the database in C#. I have looked into using SqlConnection and SqlCommand. Would these be suitable enough to connect to the database? Also, everyone has different ideas on which fields are needed in the connection string to connect to an oracle database. Username, password, and server name are the only one that I could clearly confirm that I needed.

Any information on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are tons of simple examples out there.. perhaps you're difficulties are coming into play because you are not familiar with the .Config file(s) this is very simple actually

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/

Answer (score 0):

I understand your confusion and I faced this confusion myself.  The trick is to get the conneciton info our of your Tnsnames.ora, which is typically found in

C:\oracle\product[Product Version]\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN

(Mine is C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN because my product version is 10.2.0)

The above, assumes, of course, that you've installed the Oracle client correctly, and someone has provided you with the TNSNames.ora file.

Assuming that you already have an Oracle connection set up, step 1 would be to look for a file called tnsnames.ora and look inside it.  You'll likely see things like this:

```
MyConnectionName =

(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Some.server.ulr)(PORT = 1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVICE_NAME =MyConnectionName.some.server.ulr)
(FAILOVER_MODE = (TYPE = SELECT)(METHOD = BASIC))
)
)
```

Then you can come up with your connection string:

```
connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Some.server.ulr)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyConnectionName.some.server.ulr)));User Id=MyId;Password=MyPassword;";
```

and use it in code like...

```
          using (System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection cn = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection(connectionString))
         {
              // real work here
         }
```

Comment: Oh wow, I am just now seeing this file and it has made so many more things became much more clearer. I may have one slight problem though. I am using VS2010 and under my properties, I have set the target framework to ".NETFramework 3.5". Because I have set it to this instead of ".NETFramework 4.0", if I try and manually add the assembly reference (System.Data.OracleClient) to my assembly references, I get a message saying..."No, stop, you can't add this unless you change your framework to .NetFramework 4.0" So I have also been looking at using System.Data.OleDb and System.Data.Odbc.